# Java on Linux: get the available memory

Tags: java, linux

I need to check the systems available memory in Java. I am not talking about diskspace our the memory of the JVM. I need the avaliable RAM.

formula for Linux:
available = total - free - used - buffered/cached

Posts I found point to

- com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean: addresses the total and used space but not cache/buffered or used space - so I can not calculate the available space
- Runtime: addresses the space of the JVM but not the system itself

Any other ideas before I start reading out /proc/meminfo?

Thanks for help!

Comment: For *almost all* use cases you should consider big parts buffered/cached memory to be usable. That's also why "available memory" is often a misleading metric. For example, if someone just read a huge file from disk with lots of free memory, then a huge junk of memory will be used for "caches", even when they can be freely reused. What kind of decision do you want to make based on it?

Comment: Give an indication if the systems RAM-usage is ok or an extension should be on the plan.